# I'm unable to use HTMLUnit driver with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, htmlunit

I tried that :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

I have no error but when I made a research with for example, BeautifulSoup, the program never close and so he never return me a value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Selenium Java server for this to work, since HTMLUnit is implemented on the Java side. So download it and run:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
```

Then update your code to point to it (you need to set version and platform to None):

```
from selenium import webdriver
cap = {'platform': None, 'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': None}
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=cap)
driver.get("https://google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It still return me nothing, I think there is a problem when I start java server, here's the cmd screen ( http://prntscr.com/h4hnep and http://prntscr.com/h4hnyi )

Comment: The first error is port already in use have you something else running on 4444? can you try starting it with -port 4445 and use 4445 in the command_executor string?

Comment: It works but when I try to get the source code from different website like - http://www.jeuxvideo.com/ - it don't return me anything